# How to Abort (Stop) a chain of promises, executed in a loop? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, abort, ecmascript-2017

I have a web application, in which I have two buttons: "start download" and "abort download", that are bind to the methods: `start()` and `stop()` accordingly. 
1. When the user clicks the "start download" button, the application will loop over an array of data. For each item in the array, it will call the `_downloadFile()` method that will download one file and return a `new Promise()`, once that download is complete the next download will start.
2. If during the download flow (that may take a long long time) the user clicked the "abort download" button I would like to stop the download flow.

How can I implement the abort functionality?
Here is what I got so far?

Notice that due to the fact I'm using async/await, the loop will holt until the promise is resolved, and the next iteration will only be executed once the promise is resolved (or rejected).

```
async function start(dataArray)
{
  for (let i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++)
  {
    try
    {
      let fileUrl = `http://server-url/${ i }/${ dataArray[i] }.xml`;
      let result = await _downloadFile(fileUrl);
      _saveResult(result);
    }
    catch(e) // promise rejected
    {
      _handleError(e);
    }
  }
}

function stop()
{
  // what goes here?? how do I stop the flow??
}

function _downloadFile(fileUrl)
{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  {
    // ...
  });
}

function _saveFile(data) 
{
  // ..
}

function _handleError(error)
{
  console.error("Error: " + error);
}
```

Comment: What if some of the items have already been downloaded prior to `stop` being called?

Comment: Your code does the downloads sequentially rather than in parallel; the browser can probably handle at least two if not four in parallel, which may be faster for the user.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Basically, I want to keep the data that where already saved, but this doesn't really matter because if I don't want that data I can easily delete it in the **stop** flow

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, yes I know that the download is sequential - this is by design. Since the files count is very very large. Trying to download the files parallel will cause a few problems: 1 - the server can't handle all that load and will start rejecting files at some point. 2 - The browser may end on resources (an actual error I got a few times from the browser). 3 - In some cases, I need the previously downloaded info for the future download (order matter). Nevertheless, the fact that the download is sequentially and not parallel doesn't relevant to the quastion.

Comment: No, it's not, I just thought I'd point it out in case you didn't realize (a lot of people don't understand this stuff as well as you apparently do). Sadly, JavaScript's native promises (and `await`) don't have built-in support for parallel-with-concurrency-limit like some advanced promise libs do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a flag that the function can check, and `throw` if it's set. (Well, you're actually converting rejection to resolution in your code, so maybe you don't `throw`, just return early. [I wouldn't do that, btw.])

```
let stopped = false; // *** The flag
async function start(dataArray)
{
  stopped = false;                                  // *** Re-init the flag
  for (let i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++)
  {
    try
    {
      let fileUrl = `http://server-url/${ i }/${ dataArray[i] }.xml`;
      let result = await _downloadFile(fileUrl);
      if (stopped) {                                // *** Check the flag
          return;                                   // *** and return
      }
      _saveResult(result);
    }
    catch(e) // promise rejected
    {
      _handleError(e);
    }
  }
}

function stop()
{
  // *** Set the flag
  stopped = true;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer, simple and easy to implement. I will test it